# UIImagePickerController scaling and cropping with custom overlay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

My camera's custom overlay only leaves a 320x320 square at the center so the user can take a picture of only whats on screen.

I retrieve the original picture and then I want to scale it down and crop only the area visible on the overlay.

I'm having trouble getting this to work with an iPhone5. It works for iPhone3gs, 4 and 4s.

This is the method I have been using so far:

```
-(UIImage *)squareImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    double ratio;
    double delta;
    CGPoint offset;

    //make a new square size, that is the resized imaged width
    CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.width);

    //figure out if the picture is landscape or portrait, then
    //calculate scale factor and offset
    if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.width;
        delta = (ratio*image.size.width - ratio*image.size.height);
        offset = CGPointMake(delta/2, 0);
    } else {
        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.height;
        delta = (ratio*image.size.height - ratio*image.size.width);
        if (self.isPickingFromLibrary) {
            offset = CGPointMake(0, delta/2);
        } else {
            // Add 25 for image offset
            offset = CGPointMake(0, delta/2+25);
        }
    }

    //make the final clipping rect based on the calculated values
    CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(-offset.x, -offset.y,
                                 (ratio * image.size.width) + delta,
                                 (ratio * image.size.height) + delta);


    //start a new context, with scale factor 0.0 so retina displays get
    //high quality image
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sz, YES, 0.0);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sz);
    }
    UIRectClip(clipRect);
    [image drawInRect:clipRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

On iPhone5 after running this method, the image is cropped and scaled incorrectly by a large margin.

I'm trying to make a decent custom camera for square images and I have been banging my head for a couple weeks with this. I have even looked into using AVFoundation but I don't even know where to get started.

If anyone can help me scale and crop a square image from the uiimagepicker for any device given a rect on the image I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is retina display then you should apply this code to resize your image

```
-(BOOL)iPhoneRetina{
return ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))?1:0;
```

}

```
if([self iPhoneRetina]==TRUE){

    CGRect rect =  CGRectMake(0, 0, point.origin.x, self.trackBackground.frame.size.height);
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height * [_trackImage scale];
    rect.size.width = rect.size.width * [_trackImage scale];
    rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x * [_trackImage scale];
    rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y * [_trackImage scale];
    CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [_trackImage CGImage];
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImageRef, rect);
    cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef scale:[_trackImage scale] orientation:[_trackImage imageOrientation]];

}
else{
    imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([_trackImage CGImage], CGRectMake(0, 0, point.origin.x, self.trackBackground.frame.size.height));
    cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
}
```

where rect is the rectangle of the image which has to be cropped and then resize it according to retina.